# VBA Excel- Function which returns either a number or an string

Tags: algorithm, excel, vba, analytics

I have the following code: It´s working OK but what I want to improve it´s in the final part of the code, if contador = 0, I want mespt="No se considera" instead of just returning 0.

```
    Public Function mespt(tutor As String, mes As String, j As Long) As Double


Application.Volatile

Dim a As Long
Dim totalmesp As Double


mespt = 0
contador = 0
totalmespt = 0
For i = 4 To 1000
If Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, 2).FormulaR1C1 = tutor And Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, 5).FormulaR1C1 = mes Then
Select Case Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, j).Value



Case "No cumple"
a = 0
contador = contador + 1
Case "Regular"
a = 1
contador = contador + 1
Case "Pleno"
a = 3
contador = contador + 1
Case "No se considera"
a = 0
End Select


totalmespt = totalmespt + a
If contador = 0 Then
mespt = 0
Else
mespt = totalmespt / contador
End If

End If
Next


End Function
```

I`ve used with variant in the following way:

```
Funcion mespt(                       ) as Variant
.......

if contador = 0 then
mespt="No se considera" then
mespt=totalmespt/contador
end if

end function
```

But in the case contador=0, the function just returns #!Valor

Sorry, with the variant type it's workink OK as I expect now, the problem was just with a formula in excel which works with the function mespt.

Comment: how about return as Varient.

Comment: @jsj: It is a valid answer. :) You might want to put it as an answer?

Comment: Check in my post the implementations of my code whith your recommendations, It`s not working unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, with the variant type it's workink OK as I expect now, the problem was just with a formula in excel which works with the function mespt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Variant as JSJ said.

VBA automatically converts the Variant type to the appropriate type. In the below example, the function sets its return to either a boolean or string value depending on the argument to the function.

```
Private Function returnVariant(returnBoolean As Boolean) As Variant

    If returnBoolean Then
        returnVariant = False
    Else
        returnVariant = "Hi this is a string"
    End If

End Function

Private Sub showFunctionExample()
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim v2 As Variant

    v = returnVariant(True)
    v2 = returnVariant(False)

    Debug.Print CStr(v) + "- Type: " + CStr(TypeName(v))
    Debug.Print v2 + "- Type:" + TypeName(v2)
End Sub
```

---

For your code, do:

```
Public Function mespt(tutor As String, mes As String, j As Long) As Variant


Application.Volatile

Dim a As Long
Dim totalmesp As Double


mespt = 0
contador = 0
totalmespt = 0
For i = 4 To 1000
If Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, 2).FormulaR1C1 = tutor And Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, 5).FormulaR1C1 = mes Then
Select Case Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, j).Value



Case "No cumple"
a = 0
contador = contador + 1
Case "Regular"
a = 1
contador = contador + 1
Case "Pleno"
a = 3
contador = contador + 1
Case "No se considera"
a = 0
End Select


totalmespt = totalmespt + a
If contador = 0 Then
mespt="No se considera" 
Else
mespt = totalmespt / contador
End If

End If
Next


End Function
```

Note that you will have to be careful assigning this function to variables which are not of the Variant type themselves as you will get errors if you return a string and assign it to a double.

Comment: Is there a possibility to make it work in a VBA function that I am gonna use as a custom worksheet-function ?? I tested your returnVariant function and it does not seem to work. Background - I would like to return either a double or an error message as string.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the Variant approach cause you could run into errors later on when trying to set variable with returns. I would return as a String on all accounts.

```
Public Function mespt(tutor As String, mes As String, j As Long) As String


Application.Volatile

Dim a As Long
Dim totalmesp As Double


mespt = 0
contador = 0
totalmespt = 0
For i = 4 To 1000
If Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, 2).FormulaR1C1 = tutor And Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, 5).FormulaR1C1 = mes Then
Select Case Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, j).Value



Case "No cumple"
a = 0
contador = contador + 1
Case "Regular"
a = 1
contador = contador + 1
Case "Pleno"
a = 3
contador = contador + 1
Case "No se considera"
a = 0
End Select


totalmespt = totalmespt + a
If contador = 0 Then
mespt = 0
Else
mespt = totalmespt / contador
End If

End If
Next


End Function
```

And then when using it test the return

```
Sub Sample()
IF IsNumeric(mespt("a","b","c") Then
    'Code if it comes back with a number
Else
    'Code to run if it doesn't not return number
End If
End Sub
```

***OR***

```
=if(ISNUMBER(mespt(a,b,c)), "What to do If Number is Returned", "What To do if NON-Number is returned")
```

`IsNumeric` returns *True* if the data type of Expression is **Boolean**, **Byte**, **Decimal**, **Double**, **Integer**, **Long**, **SByte**, **Short**, **Single**, **UInteger**, **ULong**, or **UShort**, or an **Object that contains one of those numeric types**. It also returns True if Expression is a Char or String that can be successfully converted to a number.

`IsNumeric` returns *False* if Expression is of data type **Date** or of data type **Object and it does not contain a numeric type**.

`IsNumeric` also returns *False* if Expression is a **Char** or **String that cannot be converted to a number**.